# Best Software for DVD long play burn

Tags: optical-media

I have a  `video.mov` file I edited with PowerDirector 15. The duration is 5 hours and I will like to burn it to a 4.7GB DVD without loosing too much quality.
What will be the recommended DVD creator for this type of large file?

I tried using the inbuilt DVD creator in PowerDirector and to fit the file to DVD, the picture quality became too poor.

How do I make things better?.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need a little more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, what is your price limit. Also note we don't give howtos here, we recommend software; and you cannot expect high quality if you want to fit 5h video in a 4.7G disk :)

Comment: I used DVDStyler at https://www.dvdstyler.org/
to solve the problem. Thanks for your concern.